# How to pass value from child component(function based component )to parent component(class based component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I need to pass the value from the child component to the parent component
The child component is function based component and parent component is class based

child component

```
export const Checkbox = (props) =>{
const [checked,setChecked] = useState(false);
return (
        <Checkbox
            label={"XYZ"}
            value={checked}
            onChange={() => setChecked((checked) =>!checked)}
            />
);
}
```

Parent Component(classbased component)

```
render(){
  return(
   <Checkbox checked={this.props.value}>//not sure if i can get value like this
)
}
```

I want to get the boolean value of the check box if it is checked or unchecked

Comment: They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) (and since yours has a useState hook, yours is not functional).

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle your state and function in the parent component and pass the function as a prop to child component and try to invoke the function call within child component on onChange to lift your state up to parent.

I am in hurry and just adding an idea how can you achieve this in code.

```
const Parent = () => {

const [checked,setChecked] = useState(false);

    const changeYourState = (newState) => {
       // change your state here
    }

    return (
        <Child
            value={checked}
            initialState={checked}
            stateHandler={changeYourState}
            />
);
}

const Child = ({ stateHandler, initialState}) => {
   //you can manipulate your initial state based on your use case 

    return (
        <div >
            onChange={() => stateHandler(initialState)}
        </div>
    )
);
}
```

Comment: if i can find small example would be good

Comment: My parent component is class based, I need checkbox value from function based to classbased component

Comment: Still the same rules apply, get and manipulate your state in child component and trigger the function that lifts your state of checkbox to the parent component.

Comment: can't we get the directly value from functional component to class based component
i want to handle the state and set state in functional component and pass those value(checked or unchecked) to classbased component